# pagination in jquery in web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, elasticsearch, pagination

I make search engine based on elastic search and connect it to web page by using ajax and jquery. when someone enters search , all match results are displayed on single web page if less than 30.In most cases I know that total match results are more than 600 but web page only display 30 results.
In console it shows like this

```
  data: Object
    hits: Object
    hits: Array[10]
    max_score : 1.2333
    total : 650
```

here total match results are 650 but web page display only 30 results.

How can I implement pagination. the code I used to display those results on web page is

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/elastic/',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {"data": text},
        success: function (response) {
            $('.pagination').remove();
            data = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(data);              
        for (var hit in data.data.hits.hits) 
          {
            var source = data.data.hits.hits[hit]._source;
            $('.div').append(source.user_name + ' / ' + 
               source.name   +'<br/>');
               }

           }, searchText = text;     }
```

Here I should implement pagination and I tried to look for relevant example of pagination here but I didn't found anything. and everytime the search result is different. sometimes there are 500 matching results and sometimes 10. 
Can someone please give me a hint/guidance or example that how pagination can be implemented. I am trying from last few days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`from` and `size` parameters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-request-from-size.html) (as query parameter or data parameter). On the other hand there is also a Scroll API. You can check it from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-request-scroll.html

Comment: @Hkullekci I know the from and size parameters, but I mean when I am displaying data in web page , there how can I use these parameters? or how can I implement pagination. .any suggestion or hint. I will be really thankful.

Comment: You can get total doc count from your result when the page load firstly. After that this count and your page size give you a page list. You can handle this logic on your controller. Then, the pagination can be written on your template. After that, every of your elasticsearch request you should send your current page number.

Comment: Thanx I got your point. but can you give me a short example or if there is already , can you point out so that I can get a better idea.